# LibGDX, How to create a 2d collision terrain

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

How can I create a surface so my bike collides with the ground?

I'm thinking of placing x,y coordinates on the surface, but that will be too straight and I want it more smooth. (I don't want to place 1 million dots)

I don't want the ground to be randomized generated, I want pre-made pictures.

See picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCevE.png

Is it possible to make a background image (the sky) and another layer with the ground displayed on top of it and then make it collide with my bike?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create more complex shapes see this :

https://code.google.com/archive/p/box2d-editor/

http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/pbe-01.jpg

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for. But how can I create the collisions for big maps/pictures? Without making 1000 pictures?